# That reoccurring heavy metal song in Fairy Tail... what is it?

Tags: music, fairy-tail

In episode 61, after they announce the name of the episode, what is the song that plays as Natsu is about to lash out?

It is more common in fight scenes, in tense situations. I thought it was going to be in the first volume of the Fairy Tail soundtrack, but I did not hear it from there.

Comment: I finally found it! It's the 13th track off of Volume 2! (Haja no Sen Kaze)

Comment: It's good that you found the answer by yourself, but you should post it as answer instead of comment. [Self-answering](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) is encouraged here!

Answer (score 1):

[According to OP themself](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/38055/that-reoccurring-heavy-metal-song-in-fairy-tail-what-is-it#comment52160_38055),

> It's the 13th track off of Volume 2, *Haja no Sen Kaze*.